# Unable to display different images from the database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am developing an e-commerce site but i am unable to display different product images from the database on my home page.
The code below displays only one image for all products while they are supposed to be different images (uploaded via the back-end).
The product name, price and category are displayed well, but not the images. I wonder why.

Here is my code

```
<?php
// connect to the database
include('variables.php');

// get the records from the database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 6";
$result = $connection->query($sql);
$getImage=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM products ") or die("Could not retrieve image: " .mysqli_error($connection));
$path=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getImage) or die("Could not fetch array : " .mysqli_error($connection));
if ($result) 
{
    // output data of each row                    
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {  
        echo '<li class="span3"><div class="product-box">';

        echo'<span class="sale_tag"></span>';

        echo'<p><a href="product_detail.php?id=' . $row["id"] . '"><img src="../backend/images/'.$path['productimage'].'" width="250" height="120"></a></p>';           
        echo  $row["name"]. "</a><br>";
        echo'<a href="products.html" class="category">' . $row["categoryname"]. '</a>';
        echo'<p class="price">KSh:' . $row["price"].'</p>';
        echo'</div></li>';
    }
}
?>
```

Kindly assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change $path to $row in the while loop

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It Works. Can i ask you another question? :)

Comment: youre welcome :). if its related you can ask here, otherwise it would be a better idea to post another

Comment: Okay. Let me post it then. Thanks